# mysql_num_rows return 0 in the second query

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code:

```
$sql    = "SELECT 
               t.id AS txn_id, 
               g.id AS guest_id, 
               a.id AS booking_id 
           FROM 
               bookings a
           LEFT JOIN transactions t ON a.txn_id=t.id
           LEFT JOIN guests g ON g.txn_id=t.id
           WHERE 
               t.code='o2-i1321209942'
           LIMIT 1";

$query  = mysql_query($sql);

$exist  = mysql_num_rows($query);

if(!$exist) {
     echo 'NOT EXISSSTTTT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!';
} else {
     echo 'EXISSSTTTT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!';
}
```

> Note: data exists in the database

When I click submit from a form it will display "NOT EXISSSTTTT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" and then when I refresh the page or press Ctrl+F5 it will display "EXISSSTTTT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" and when I refresh it again it will display "NOT EXISSSTTTT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" again.

It acts like:

Submit: Not Exists

Refresh: Exists

2nd Refresh: Not Exists

3rd Refresh: Exists

Any suggestion why is it working weird? Any answer will be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Where is your mysql connection done?

Comment: When you submit the form, is any of the information you're submitting being included in the query? Can you include the form markup?

Comment: It's Sunday morning, why all the yelling?

Comment: @tandu: yes, mysql connection is done. that's why it will return a 1 for first mysql_num_rows query.

Comment: @JaredFarrish with or without the data from form. it will act weird.

Answer (score 1):

Your code outputs "not exist" if the query returns 0 rows or the query fails (`mysql_num_rows` returns `FALSE` in case of error). So I guess you have a connection related problem (or maybe you construct query dynamically and not escape some data). You can track it down by outputting error information:

```
$query  = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()) ;

$exist  = mysql_num_rows($query);
```

Comment: I already tried outputting error but there's no error on the query. The problem is when I refresh the page the mysql_num_rows output will change alternately. Like 1st refresh it will return 1 then next refresh it will display 0. Maybe escaping of data is the problem. Could help me how to do that?

Comment: Do you get the value of `t.code` from the form ? Or it's always `'o2-i1321209942'` ?

Comment: That looks really weird to me. Are you sure you don't update anything in database that affect the number of records returning by the query in your code? If you say it always returns 0 then 1 row and no errors, my assumption that some piece of code updates database.